# Convert a Matrix of doubles to a grayscale .tif image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, tiff

I have an nCol by nRow matrix of doubles that I want to convert into an nCol by nRow grayscale images of pixels. I don't want to cut this down to an image scaled to 256 channels. I'd be happy with using singles instead of doubles. I've looked through the Tiff class documentation from Mathworks but can't find a simple example for this.

Comment: What is the values of your matrix? Because just two dimensional matrix is already grayscale. Colour images has much dimensions.
Just try `imshow(yourmatrix)`

Comment: This is not what I'm after.

Comment: Then show some examples pls.

Comment: If I run imshow and then save as an image the resolution is different to nCol by nRow pixels. I don't want to have to change the settings in the figure and call `saveas`, that is inefficient. I'd rather just use the `Tiff class` in Matlab and write the image directly.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to read about Tiff class and yep it is very poor documented. But I found this going through trial and error:

lets say we have matrix

```
data = rand(100,200);
```

Lets save it as Tiff:

```
t  = Tiff('new.tif','w')                                   %create object of Tiff class
setTag(t,Tiff.TagID.ImageLength,size(data,1))              %define image dimentions
setTag(t,Tiff.TagID.ImageWidth,size(data,2))

setTag(t,'Photometric', Tiff.Photometric.MinIsBlack)       %define the color type of image

%specifies how image data components are stored on disk
setTag(t,'PlanarConfiguration',Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky);

setTag(t,'BitsPerSample',64);                              %because 1 double = 8byte = 64bits

%Specify how to interpret each pixel sample (IEEEFP works with input doubles)
setTag(t,'SampleFormat',Tiff.SampleFormat.IEEEFP);         
t.write(data)
t.close
```

Lets test this now:

```
datac = imread('new.tif')
whos datac
Name         Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes
datac      100x200            160000  double
```

And:

```
datac(:,1)

ans =

0.4921
0.6908
0.1544
0.4433
...
```

Comment: Thanks for this - actually I have done something similar but when trying to open the `.tif` in Windows I get an error saying that the file is corrupt. I can, however, open the image in Matlab. Any ideas why Windows sees a corrupt file?

Comment: First of all I was thinking about 'RowsPerStrip' property because it had an incorrect value. But fixing this value didn't helped!
I think the problem is that Windows can't recognize tiff with doubles! Also since tiff is always 3d matrix, maybe it's not correct to create 2d tiff...